# HTTP Redirect from subdomain to node.js app showing incorrect URL

Tags: node.js, http, dns, web-hosting, subdomain

I've been banging my head against the wall all week on this. Long story short, I have a domain that is hosted with 1and1. I also have several node.js apps that are hosted with nodejitsu. Each node.js app is a customized instance of our product for different clients. Every client gets a subdomain under our parent domain that points to their instance on nodejitsu. Example: `acme.myproductname.com` points to our node.js instance running at `acme.acmenodejitsuappname.jit.su`, and `companyA.myproductname.com` points to our node.js instance running at `companyA.companyAnodejitsuappname.jit.su`.

For literally the past 2 years, when I configure a new subdomain for clients, I create the subdomain on 1and1 and set up a regular (no frame-masking) HTTP Redirect to the URL of the instance running on nodejitsu. Within about 5-10 minutes it takes effect and everything works fine. The newest one I set up is NOT working. The HTTP redirect is working, but the URL it shows in the address bar is the nodejitsu instance (i.e. `acme.acmenodejitsuappname.jit.su`) instead of the original subdomain URL (i.e. `acme.myproductname.com`). It is configured exactly the same as all the previous ones I've done on both the 1and1 side and the nodejitsu side. The package.json file in the node.js app also has the correct "domains" array that tells nodejitsu what domain names the app should handle.

It may be worthwhile to note that I had the same problem a couple weeks ago with a domain that I have hosted with GoDaddy on a completely separate project. The HTTP redirect worked but it showed the nodejitsu instance URL. I was able to fix this by modifying the A-record settings of the domain (as it was a top-level domain, not a subdomain) to point to nodejitsu, and it worked great. I can't do that with this project because they are subdomains instead of top-level domains.

What in the world is going on? Was there in change how HTTP redirects work recently? Is there something I should have in my node.js code that rewrites the nodejitsu URL to the subdomain that forwarded to it? I haven't had to have that in the past so I'm kind of at a loss as to why it's different now.

Thanks in advance! You guys rock!

Comment: can you put some code on how you redirect?

Comment: @esc it's just configured in the 1and1 UI. I just click the subdomain and select a destination of HTTP Redirect, then I specify the URL to redirect to. That's all the settings they give me, there is no code.